# Rolling die until number is greater than 100

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Probability of dice sum just greater than 100](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12433/probability-of-dice-sum-just-greater-than-100)

A die is rolled several times and the number appearing is summed. We stop when this sum becomes greater than or equal to 100. What value of sum in the end is the most probable (out of 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105)?

105 can be generated in only 1 way : 99 + 6

104 can be generated in only 2 ways: 99 + 5, 98 + 6

and so on.

Assuming that the dice rolling will reach either of numbers in range [94,99] is equally likely, 100 is the most likely. Am I correct?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12433/probability-of-dice-sum-just-greater-than-100

Comment: "Assuming that the dice rolling will reach either of numbers in range [94,99] is equally likely, 100 is the most likely." That's a big assumption.

Comment: The answer for this problem can be much simpler than that of @woz. The expected number of each roll is: 1/6*(1+2+3+4+5+6) = 3.5. When the sum > 100, the minimum numb of turns N needed to be taken is 30 that 30*3.5 = 105. Voilà!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let a<sub>n</sub> be the number of ways to get a sum of n:

a<sub>100</sub> = a<sub>99</sub> + a<sub>98</sub> + a<sub>97</sub> + a<sub>96</sub> + a<sub>95</sub> + a<sub>94</sub>

a<sub>101</sub> = a<sub>99</sub> + a<sub>98</sub> + a<sub>97</sub> + a<sub>96</sub> + a<sub>95</sub>

a<sub>102</sub> = a<sub>99</sub> + a<sub>98</sub> + a<sub>97</sub> + a<sub>96</sub>

a<sub>103</sub> = a<sub>99</sub> + a<sub>98</sub> + a<sub>97</sub>

a<sub>104</sub> = a<sub>99</sub> + a<sub>98</sub>

a<sub>105</sub> = a<sub>99</sub>

So you can see just from this that a<sub>100</sub> is the most likely since there are more ways to get to a sum of 100.

**In plain language...**

In other words, you might have the opportunity to end a game at 100 by rolling a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6, but you can only end a game at 105 by rolling a 6 on your last roll.

**Sum at the penultimate roll**

I disagree that sums of [94,99] are all equally likely for your penultimate roll, but it doesn't matter if they are equal or not. It's the last roll that determines the total score, which is the focus here. There are still a<sub>98</sub> + a<sub>97</sub> + a<sub>96</sub> + a<sub>95</sub> + a<sub>94</sub> more ways to get a sum of 100 than there are to get a sum of 105, for example.

Comment: This suppose that that getting $94,95,...99$ is equally likely, but   this is not true

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: It doesn't suppose that. We have $a_{100}\gt a_{101}$ independent of the values of $a_{94}$ through $a_{99}$, simply because the difference is $a_{94}$ and hence positive.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien They don't have to be equally likely. There are still $a_{98}$  + $a_{97}$ + $a_{96}$ + $a_{95}$ + $a_{94}$ more ways to get 100 than there are to get 105.

Comment: Right, sorry, don't know where i got this off