# What is the probability to get sum $k$ by throwing a die?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice, dynamic-programming

Suppose we start at the number zero, and repeatedly roll a fair $6$-sided die, adding the resulting number to the total. We win if we reach the total $k$, and lose if we overshoot, for example by reaching a total of $k-1$ and then rolling a number greater than $1$. What is the probability to win?

Comment: Well, there's a simple recursion ($P_n=\frac 16 \times \left(P_{n-6}+\cdots P_{n-1}\right)$).  Were you looking for the limit as $k\to \infty$ or something like that?

Comment: k is a fixed number. I thought a dynamic programming solution but I am not sure it's the fastest and if it's correct at all.

Comment: Ok, but then the recursion works.  It's linear so you can solve it in closed form (though the characteristic polynomial has degree $6$ so the closed form isn't very nice).

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978036/what-are-the-odds-of-hitting-exactly-100-rolling-a-fair-die) was technically about the case $k=100$ but the answers discuss the general case. The limiting probability is $2/7.$

Comment: How does one get such a recursion?

Comment: @Kaynex  In order to  reach $k$ exactly one has to do exactly one of the following:  for some $i\in [1,\cdots,6]$ you must reach $k-i$ and then throw an $i$.  The recursion just restates that.

Comment: @Kaynex $P_n$ is your probability of hitting $n$ if you start from $0.$ On your first roll you are equally likely to roll $1,2,3,4,5,6.$ If you start by rolling $k$ your conditional probability of hitting $n$ is $P_{n-k},$ the probability of hitting $n-k$ with your subsequent rolls. $P_n$ is the average of those six conditional probabilities.

Comment: @lulu Yes, that's another way to look at it. Reels the mind.